# Keep getting kernel error when trying to install VM using kickstart file on centos8

Tags: linux, centos

This is the first time that i ask a question in here and i am hopping someone can help me with this problem i am having installing a VM on my centos8 server using kickstart file. I have follow guides from youtube, linkedin course and other site that provide guides to install with kickstart file.
I do have some linux skills but i still see myself as a beginner.

The problem that i am having is when i try to install a VM from terminal using a kickstart file i get an error with the kernel. I tried to remove the kickstart commando to see if it would run and setup the VM without installing the OS and it did. I then tried to remove the some of the argument in the kickstart commando to see if it was one of them that was the problem but i just keep getting the same error. I commando that i use is below and i also tried it with a centos8 images but i am getting the same error with that one.

I get the kickstart file by install a VM manually and copy the file over so that i know what the setup is going to be.

> virt-install --name centos7-ks --ram 2048 --os-variant=centos7.0 --cdrom=/home/install/CentOS-7-x86_64-DVD-2003.iso --nographics --disk path=/var/lib/libvirt/images/centos7-ks.qcow2,size=20,bus=virtio,format=qcow2 --initrd-inject=/home/install/anaconda-Centos7-ks.cfg --extra-args="ks=anaconda-Centos7-ks.cfg ip=dhcp console=tty0 console=ttyS0,115200n8"

> ERROR    Kernel arguments are only supported with location or kernel installs.

I tried to look up the error but i was not able to fine anything about it and i ask everyone i know that knows about linux and they don´t know what the problem is. I am really hopping that someone in here can help.

Answer (score 1):

You need to replace parameter `cdrom` by parameter `location`:

> virt-install --name centos7-ks --ram 2048 --os-variant=centos7.0 --**location**=/home/install/CentOS-7-x86_64-DVD-2003.iso --nographics --disk path=/var/lib/libvirt/images/centos7-ks.qcow2,size=20,bus=virtio,format=qcow2 --initrd-inject=/home/install/anaconda-Centos7-ks.cfg --extra-args="ks=anaconda-Centos7-ks.cfg ip=dhcp console=tty0 console=ttyS0,115200n8"

I hope this solves your problem.

Comment: Hi Thanks for the reply. I tried it out and it started the process but it stop saying "Warning: unknown network kickstart URL: anaconda-Centos7-ks.cfg"

[   15.313942] sr 0:0:0:0: [sr0] scsi3-mmc drive: 4x/4x cd/rw xa/form2 tray
[   15.316544] cdrom: Uniform CD-ROM driver Revision: 3.20
[   15.824079] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): eth0: link becomes ready
[   19.833445] dracut-initqueue[724]: RTNETLINK answers: File exists
[   20.488644] dracut-initqueue[724]: Warning: unknown network kickstart URL: anaconda-Centos7-ks.cfg